# Partition List on sublists where similar elements to be grouped

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a `List<object>` elements. The list is huge. The list size would be around 1M records. I am trying to partition the list to get the min and max for each partition, which I will be passing them to the DB queries.
I am currently doing this in the following way:

```
int gridSize = 6;
List<object> objectList = findAll();
List<List<object>> partitionedList = ListUtils.partition(objectList, (objectList.size() + gridSize - 1) / gridSize);
for(List<object> objects : partitionedList) {
    List<Long> keys = objects.stream().map(x -> x.getKey()).collect(Collectors.toList());
    //Do some processing on keys collected in the above list
    LongSummaryStatistics idStats = objects.stream().collect(Collectors.summarizingLong(e -> e));
    repo.callToDb(idStats.getMin(), idStats.getMax());
    //further processing
}
```

The above code works fine but I have repeated keys in my objects like this:
Input:

```
Car[id: 1, name:Tesla, Key: 1]
Car[id: 2, name:Tesla-3, Key: 2]
Car[id: 3, name:Tesla-Y, Key: 2]
Car[id: 4, name:Tesla-S, Key: 3]
```

When I do a Partition with the above code with chunk size: 2 I get the partition as:

```
Partition-1:
Car[id: 1, name:Tesla, Key: 1]
Car[id: 2, name:Tesla-3, Key: 2]

Partition-2:
Car[id: 3, name:Tesla-Y, Key: 2]
Car[id: 4, name:Tesla-S, Key: 3]
```

Instead I want the keys from the first partition to not be repeated on the second partition.

So, essentially I want the partition to look like this:

```
Partition-1:
Car[id: 1, name:Tesla, Key: 1]
Car[id: 2, name:Tesla-3, Key: 2]
Car[id: 3, name:Tesla-Y, Key: 2]

Partition-2:
Car[id: 4, name:Tesla-S, Key: 3]
```

Is there a way I can achieve this with a chunk size as mentioned. Thanks in advance!

Edit:
Here is what I wrote:

```
int gridSize = 6;
List<List<object>> partitionedList = new ArrayList<>();
Map<Integer, Pair<Long, Long>> minMaxPairMap = new HashMap<>();
List<object> objectList = findAll();
List<object> uniqueKeys = objectList.stream()
                .filter(distinctByKey(x -> x.getKey())).collect(Collectors.toList());
List<List<object>> uniqueKeysPartition = ListUtils.partition(uniqueKeys,
                (uniqueKeys.size() + gridSize - 1) / gridSize);
for (int i = 0; i < uniqueKeysPartition.size(); i++) {
    List<object> ojList = uniqueKeysPartition.get(i);
            LongSummaryStatistics longSummaryStatistics = ojList.stream().map(object::getKey).collect(Collectors.toList()).stream().collect(Collectors.summarizingLong(e -> e));
    minMaxPairMap.put(i, Pair.of(longSummaryStatistics.getMin(), longSummaryStatistics.getMax()));
    partitionedList.add(objectList.subList(
                    getFirstIndexOf(objectList, longSummaryStatistics.getMin()),
                    getLastIndexOf(objectList, longSummaryStatistics.getMax()) + 1));
}
for (int i = 0; i < partitionedList.size(); i++) {
    List<Long> keys = objects.stream().map(x -> x.getKey()).collect(Collectors.toList());
    //Do some processing on keys collected in the above list
    Pair<Long, Long> minMaxPair = minMaxPairMap.get(i);
    repo.callToDb(minMaxPair.getFirst(), minMaxPair.getSecond());
    //further processing
}
```

Is there a better way to achieve this because I feel I have complicated it to achieve what I want?

Comment: So you want to avoid splitting keys between partitions and treat the partition size as a minimum?

Comment: You are almost certainly going to need to give up on any sort of existing `ListUtils` or `stream`; you are going to need to do this manually.

Comment: Yes, Thats correct. Keys shouldn't be split between partitions and the size of the partition can be the maximum number of elements the sublist can contain.

Comment: It can't be a maximum. What if there are too many identical keys?

Comment: True. my bad. It's the minimum

Comment: @shmosel May I know how to do avoid splitting keys between partitions

Answer (score 0):

Moving the partition bounds only makes sense if the data is sorted or at least clustered by the key, as otherwise, additional occurrences could exist in arbitrary other partitions.

If the data is sorted, the task is rather trivial. Do what methods like `ListUtils.partition` do but add a check whether the last element’s key of a partition matches the next partition’s first element’s and if so, increase the end index of the partition:

```java
static <T, K extends Comparable<? super K>> List<List<T>> partition(
    List<T> data, int minSize, Function<T, K> keyFunction) {

    List<T> workingCopy = new ArrayList<>(data);
    workingCopy.sort(Comparator.comparing(keyFunction));

    List<List<T>> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int ix = 0, ix2; ix < data.size(); ix = ix2) {
        ix2 = Math.min(workingCopy.size(), ix + minSize);
        for(K lastKey = keyFunction.apply(workingCopy.get(ix2 - 1));
            ix2 < data.size()
            && Objects.equals(lastKey, keyFunction.apply(workingCopy.get(ix2)));) {
            ix2++;
        }
        result.add(workingCopy.subList(ix, ix2));
    }

    return result;
}
```

This can be tested like

```java
record TestObj(int key, String name) {}

List<TestObj> objectList = IntStream.range('A', 'Z')
    .mapToObj(c -> new TestObj(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0, 10),
                               "" + (char)c))
    .toList();

List<List<TestObj>> partitions = partition(objectList, 6, TestObj::key);

System.out.println(partitions.size() + " partitions");

for(List<TestObj> p: partitions) {
    System.out.println("(" + p.size() + " elements)");
    p.forEach(System.out::println);
    System.out.println();
}
```

[Test on jdoodle.com](https://jdoodle.com/ia/LU9)

Note that if the key is not `Comparable` you can turn the sort operation into a clustering operation like

```java
Map<Object, Integer> chunkID = new HashMap<>();
List<List<TestObj>> partitions = partition(objectList, 6,
    o -> chunkID.computeIfAbsent(o.key(), k -> chunkID.size()));
```

Since this assigns each distinct key an ascending number in the order of occurrence, which is then used for sorting, it will minimize the changes made to the encounter order, making no changes if the elements are already clustered.